# HTML string is not appended

Tags: jquery, html, string, append

I have a variable containing a string of HTML

```
var myhtml = "<div><a>DEMO</a></div>";
```

Before I append the HTML, I want to make changes to it, so I do this.

```
$("body").append( $(myhtml).filter("a").addClass("testing") );
```

However, nothing is appended, and I get no console errors. How can I alter the HTML and still append it normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two things to take into account:

1. [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) changes the jQuery object on which it is called. In your case, it will only keep `a` and remove the parent `div`. You should use [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) instead.`find` will return a new jQuery object without altering the original one.
2. However, you cannot directly insert the result of the calls chain into your DOM. `find` returns a *new* jQuery object that only contains `a`. If you want to keep the parent `div`, you must insert the first jQuery object.

```js
var myhtml = "<div><a>DEMO</a></div>";
// Parse the string into a jquery object.
var $myhtml = $(myhtml);
// Add the "testing" class to the `a` child(ren).
$myhtml.find("a").addClass("testing");
// Add a class to the root of $myhtml (i.e. the `div`) if needed.
$myhtml.addClass("div-class");
// Append the jquery object.
$("body").append($myhtml);
```

```css
.testing {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.div-class {
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: solid; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks. How would I go about making multiple alterations? For example how would I add a class to the div element as well?

Comment: The `div` element is the root of your jQuery object so you can just use `addClass` on `$myhtml`.

Answer (score 1):

Enjoy =)

```
var myhtml = "<div><a>DEMO</a></div>";
$("body").append($(myhtml).find('a').addClass("testing"))
```

Ok, with div:

```
var myhtml = "<div><a>DEMO</a></div>";
var $div = $(myhtml);
$div.find('a').addClass("testing");
$("body").append($div);
```

Good luck!

Comment: or you want just to add class testing to "a" and append body with whole div?

Comment: I have tried to use find and I only get 'a' returned, but not the rest of the HTML